# Contextualized bindings with NInject

Tags: c#, ninject

I've an interface `IInterface`, and two imeplmentations `Impl1` and `Impl2`.

Each implementation is annotated with an `KeyAttribute`:

```
[Key("key1")]
public class Impl1 : IInterface {}

[Key("key2")]
public class Impl2 : IInterface {}
```

`Impl1` is in an assembly and `Impl2` in another one.

Im creating binding by convention:

```
this.Bind(b => b.FromAssembliesMatching("*")
            .SelectAllClasses()
            .InheritedFrom(typeof(IInterface))
            .BindAllInterfaces()
        );
```

By configuration, my project has a configuration like a list of `<user, backend>`, where `backend` is the backend key will be associated with.

When I load users configuration, I need to `Get` the implementation associated where `implementation.KeyAttribute.Equals(currentUser)`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Configure` method to create a named binding:

```
kernel.Bind(x => x
    .FromThisAssembly()
    .SelectAllClasses()
    .InheritedFrom<IInterface>()
    .BindAllInterfaces()
    .Configure((syntax, type) => syntax.Named(GetKeyFrom(type))));

private static string GetKeyFrom(Type type)
{
    return type
        .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(KeyAttribute), false)
        .OfType<KeyAttribute>()
        .Single()
        .Key;
}
```

then resolve it with:

```
kernel.Get<IInterface>("key1");
kernel.Get<IInterface>("key2");
```

---

Here's all my code (for verification purposes):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using FluentAssertions;
using Ninject;
using Ninject.Extensions.Conventions;
using Xunit;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class KeyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public KeyAttribute(string key)
    {
        Key = key;
    }

    public string Key { get; private set; }
}

public interface IInterface { }

[Key("key1")]
public class Impl1 : IInterface { }

[Key("key2")]
public class Impl2 : IInterface { }

public class Test
{
    [Fact]
    public void Foo()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind(x => x
            .FromThisAssembly()
            .SelectAllClasses()
            .InheritedFrom<IInterface>()
            .BindAllInterfaces()
            .Configure((syntax, type) => syntax.Named(GetKeyFrom(type))));

        kernel.Get<IInterface>("key1").Should().BeOfType<Impl1>();
        kernel.Get<IInterface>("key2").Should().BeOfType<Impl2>();
    }

    private static string GetKeyFrom(Type type)
    {
        return type
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(KeyAttribute), false)
            .OfType<KeyAttribute>()
            .Single()
            .Key;
    }
}
```